# set highchart margin

Tags: javascript, highcharts, margin

I have built some highcharts charts and I am displaying them one at a time
on mouseover. 
The jquery creates a floating div (depending on the cursor) with a border line

```
1px solid black
```

and then the highchart method is being called to draw the chart.

The thing is that highcharts exceed the boundary and left and bottom border is not shown.

I tried 'margin' :

```
chart:
    {
      renderTo: 'graph',
      defaultSeriesType: 'line',
      zoomType: 'x',
      margin: [ 10, 10, 10, 10]
    },
```

and still it does the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set the margins to at least 70 in order for the highchart to display decently.  Also, if you are using and you know the size of the div you may want to specify the [**height**](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--height) and [**width**](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--width) of the chart as well.  I would make it slightly smaller than the div.  Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/xP6j9/).